# Present Perfect Simple vs Past Simple

Tags: british-english

> How much has it cost?
>   My father has paid for it. That's why I don't know its price.

vs

> How much did it cost?
>   My father paid for it. That's why I don't know its price.

Which one is more correct ?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second example ['How much did it cost?'] sounds more natural to me.  I'd only use the perfect tense [paradoxically] for some on-going business, such as "Building this garage *has already cost* me £2000." [With the implication that it's going to cost me more,]

Comment: Can anyone explain the down vote?

Comment: Hi, David. I am not the downvoter, but which is correct? type of question doesn't work well here. And the question was closed as off-topic. It might be the reason. :-)

Comment: My English teacher said that the Present Perfect question was absolutely wrong.Is she right?

Comment: Thank-you, @Rathony.  Perhaps it was already closed, but I just saw the question, and answered it.  Now I can see it was put On Hold before I did that.